# How to insert Hexcode within string template literal

Tags: javascript

Right now I have the following in my `<div>`

```
{<span>&#35;</span>}
      {`${totalQuantity}`} <span>&#8377;</span>
      {`${totalCost}`}
```

This outputs `#0₹0` ('totalQuantity' & 'totalCost' are variables with value of zero as of now)

However, as you can see, I have 2 span's & 2 template literals because I do not know how to insert the hex code of # & ₹ into template literal. How do I do that? Can I even do that?

Comment: Same way you would insert any html in a string. `\`&#35;${totalQuantity} &#8377;${totalCost}\``

Comment: @Ouroborus That was simple! I was overthinking it. Since it was react component! Now I just have `&#35; {totalQuantity} ({totalDishes}) &#8377; {totalCost}` (not even backticks!) and it works. If you put your suggestion as answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) are a part of HTML (their long name is "HTML Entity") and so can be treated similar to how you might do `.innerHTML = '<div></div>'`.

For example,

```
someElement.innerHTML = `&#35;${totalQuantity} &#8377;${totalCost}`;
```

Note that since HTML5 documents are encouraged to be encoded as UTF-8, you can also do the following (though you may have reasons not to):

```
someElement.innerHTML = `#${totalQuantity} ₹${totalCost}`;
```